# Pygame enemy display random when player moves by keyboard

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am building a football game (american) that has a Player class move an image by the keyboard in one program:

```
import pygame
import os
import random

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 100, 0)


# This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player controls
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player_one.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.width = 15
        self.height = 15
        self.x = 940
        self.y = 240

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if self.y < 470:
                self.y += self.height
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.y > 0:
                self.y -= self.height
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.x < 940:
                self.x += self.width
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.x > 0:
                self.x -= self.width

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    player.handle_keys()

    screen.fill(green)

    for x in range(60,940,35):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, [x, 0], [x, 500], 1)

    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(20)
```

And another program that displays the enemy randomly on a background image when any key is pressed they change position:

```
import random
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Enemy():

    def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

    #------------

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    #------------

    def update(self):
        # here change randomly positon
        self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,500))

        self.background = pygame.image.load("GameField1.png").convert()
        self.multi_enemies = []
        self.players = []

        # create 3 enemies 0...2

        for i in range(0,3):
            enemy = Enemy("enemy_"+str(i)+".png")
            enemy.update() # set random position on start
            self.multi_enemies.append(enemy)


    #------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        RUNNING = True

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False

                    # changes position when key is pressed


                    for enemy in self.multi_enemies:
                        enemy.update()

                    for player in self.players:
                        player.handle_keys()

            # --- updates ---- 

            # place for updates

            # --- draws ---


            self.screen.fill(BLACK)

            self.screen.blit(self.background, self.background.get_rect())

            for enemy in self.multi_enemies:
                enemy.draw(self.screen)


            pygame.display.update()

            pygame.display.flip()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(20)

        # --- quit ---

        pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

First - Thank you for the people who helped me get this far. Second - I need to combine the Player class to the second program. I need to add collision detection so that if the player makes it to the left end zone his Score increases +7 and he goes back to the start. Also, if the player runs into an Enemy then he goes back to the start. I want the game to be on a 2 min timer so the goal is to score as much within the timeframe before the game ends.

I know a lot of people are going to recommend Sprites and I expect that but could you please provide code/explanation. Attached are my images.

[image: player1]

[image: enemy2]

[image: enemy1]

[image: enemy0]

[image: gamefield]

Comment: Copy Player class into second program. Or put only Player class to separated file (`Player.py`) and import it to second program (`from Player import *`). Then you have to connect (somehow) both mainloops into one mainloop. And then you can start to think how to do rest of you ideas - score increasing,  2 min timer, etc. You have a lot of work to do :)

Comment: Connecting the main loops has been my biggest issue. I did copy the player class in on one attempt and then added the "player.handle_keys()" to the loop but it wouldn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split code into 3 files `Player.py`, `Enemy.py` and `Game.py`

**Player.py**

- I add `restart()` to set start position at new game and game restart
- In `handle_event` I use event (to check keys) so I could check mouse events and other events if I have to - it is more universal.
- `handle_event` return `True/False` if player was moved or not.

.

```
import pygame

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, surface_rect):

        self.surface_rect = surface_rect

        self.image = pygame.image.load("player_one.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey( (255,255,255) )

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() # you get image width, height

        self.move_x = 15
        self.move_y = 15

        self.restart()

    #------------

    def restart(self):

        self.rect.x = 940
        self.rect.y = 240

    #------------

    def handle_events(self, event):
        player_moves = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if self.rect.bottom < self.surface_rect.bottom: #470
                    self.rect.y += self.move_y
                    player_moves = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if self.rect.top > self.surface_rect.top:
                    self.rect.y -= self.move_y
                    player_moves = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if self.rect.right < self.surface_rect.right:
                    self.rect.x += self.move_x
                    player_moves = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if self.rect.left > self.surface_rect.left:
                    self.rect.x -= self.move_x
                    player_moves = True

            print "(debug): player: x, y:", self.rect.x, self.rect.y

        return player_moves
    #------------

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Enemy.py**

nothing is changed

```
import pygame
import random

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Enemy():

    def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey( (255,255,255) )

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

    #------------

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    #------------

    def update(self):
        # here change randomly positon
        self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60, 220+1), random.randint(0, 475+1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Game.py**

best part :) try to figure out what is going on in code ;)

- collision detect - it could be use [pygame.sprite.Sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), [pygame.sprite.Group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), etc.
- score for player and enemies
- time counting
- game over - `backspace` restart game after game over

.

```
import random
import pygame

from Player import *
from Enemy import *

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )
RED   = (255,0  ,0  )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,500))

        self.background = pygame.image.load("GameField1.png").convert()

        self.enemies = []
        #self.players = []
        self.player = Player(self.screen.get_rect())

        # create 3 enemies 0...2

        for i in range(3):
            enemy = Enemy("enemy_"+str(i)+".png")
            enemy.update() # set random position on start
            self.enemies.append(enemy)

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 32)

        self.gameover_text = self.font.render("GAME OVER", -1, RED)
        self.gameover_rect = self.gameover_text.get_rect(center=self.screen.get_rect().center)

        self.restart()

    #------------

    def restart(self):

        self.player_score = 0
        self.enemies_score = 0

        #self.play_time = 2*60 # 2minutes * 60 seconds
        self.play_time = 30 # 30 seconds for fast test
        self.change_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000 # 1s

        self.player.restart()

    #------------

    def update_time(self):
        print "(debug): time:", self.change_time, pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= self.change_time:
            self.change_time += 1000 # 1s
            self.play_time -= 1

        return self.play_time <= 0 # GAME OVER ?

    #------------

    def draw_score(self, surface):
        surface_rect = surface.get_rect()

        self.player_score_text = self.font.render(str(self.player_score) + " :Player", -1, WHITE)
        self.player_score_rect = self.player_score_text.get_rect(right=surface_rect.right-10, top=10)

        surface.blit(self.player_score_text, self.player_score_rect)

        self.enemies_score_text = self.font.render("Enemy: " + str(self.enemies_score), -1, WHITE)
        self.enemies_score_rect = self.enemies_score_text.get_rect(left=surface_rect.left+10, top=10)

        surface.blit(self.enemies_score_text, self.enemies_score_rect)

        print "(debug): render scores:", self.player_score, self.player_score_rect, self.enemies_score, self.enemies_score_rect

    #------------

    def draw_time(self, surface):
        surface_rect = surface.get_rect()

        time_str = "%02d:%02d" % (self.play_time/60, self.play_time%60)

        self.time_text = self.font.render(time_str, -1, RED )
        self.time_rect = self.time_text.get_rect(centerx=surface_rect.centerx, top=10)

        surface.blit(self.time_text, self.time_rect)

        print "(debug): render time:", self.play_time, self.time_rect, (self.play_time/60, self.play_time%60), time_str 

    #------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True
        GAME_OVER = False

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            PLAYER_MOVES = False

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False

                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        if GAME_OVER:
                            GAME_OVER = False
                            self.restart()

                # player moves

                if not GAME_OVER:
                    PLAYER_MOVES = self.player.handle_events(event)

            # --- updates ---- 

            if PLAYER_MOVES and not GAME_OVER:

                # changes position when key is pressed

                for enemy in self.enemies:
                    enemy.update()

                # check collisions

                collision = False
                for enemy in self.enemies:
                    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, enemy):
                        collision = True
                        break # first collision and I don't check rest enemies

                if collision:
                    self.enemies_score += 7
                    print "(debug): game: collision:", self.player_score, self.enemies_score
                    self.player.restart()

                # check touchdown

                if self.player.rect.left <= 100:
                    self.player_score += 7
                    print "(debug): game: touchdown:", self.player_score, self.enemies_score
                    self.player.restart()

            if not GAME_OVER:
                GAME_OVER = self.update_time()

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(BLACK)

            self.screen.blit(self.background, self.background.get_rect())

            self.player.draw(self.screen)

            for enemy in self.enemies:
                enemy.draw(self.screen)

            self.draw_time(self.screen)
            self.draw_score(self.screen)

            if GAME_OVER:
                self.screen.blit(self.gameover_text, self.gameover_rect)

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(20) 

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to what you are asking, I hope this will answer all your questions:

First of all wouldn't the enemies "teleport" to random locations each time they update? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but it should be better if you randomize their location on init (where you set their x and y to 0 ) and on the update you should create some Artificial Intelligence (like following the hero? )

```
class Enemy():

def __init__(self, image):

    self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
    self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.centerx = random.randint(60,220+1)
    self.rect.centery = random.randint( 0, 475+1)

#------------

def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#------------

def update(self, heroX, heroY):
    #Make enemies follow hero (for example)
    if heroX > self.rect.centerx
        self.rect.centerx += 10; #10 is example value, set the one you like!
    else if heroX < self.rect.centerx
        self.rect.centerx -= 10;

    #Do the same for y

#------------

def reset(self): #This is called when hero scores, or enemies touch hero (and you want to reset hero to starting point and enemies)
    self.rect.centerx = random.randint(60,220+1)
    self.rect.centery = random.randint( 0, 475+1)
```

Just make sure to pass player's x and y when you update the enemy.

About collision, there is a simple algorithm that goes like that: If you have objectA and objectB they only collide **if** objectA.right > objectB.left && objectA.left < objectB.right , combine top and bottoms the same way and you are done

```
if (player.right > enemy.left && player.left < enemy.right && player.bottom > enemy.top && player.top < enemy.bottom)
    player.reset()
    enemy.reset()
```

apply this algorithm once for each enemy (and hero, if there are more than one)

About the timer, you already have a timer to limit frames, you can use that to count seconds inside the game and create limits (use your imagination!)

Comment: When you say "pass player's x and y when you update the enemy" are you saying during the event loop? Also - would I need to set heroX = hero.rect.centerx or could I pass that by itself?

Comment: by pass player's x and y I mean something like that:

`enemy.update(player.rect.x, player.rect.y)`

so enemies know where to move

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sprites! I'm not going to tell you everything because figuring game programming out is half the fun! 
First of all, you could set pygame groups up, like 
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player) 
for player and enemy, and test a collision between them both using pygame.sprite.spritecollide and maybe something similar for your left zone of the pitch.. 
Then as furas mentioned, just copy or import player class. :)
Also, I would suggest pygame.time.get_ticks() for your timer, although you can do it other ways.. 
The rest is down to you! I hope this helped in some way, ask any questions if you don't understand!
I have done this on a phone so if someone wants to edit it for all the codey bits that'd be great :)

Comment: I think an issue is that I'm calling my images in two separate ways in the Player class vs the Enemy Class. I'm not sure which one to stick with and I'm not certain on what self.rect = self.image.get_rect() is doing on the Enemy Class. Is it getting the min width and height of a rectangle the image could fit?

Comment: Basically, yeah! get_rect() just returns a new rectangle the size of the surface, so in your case, the image and it will have the same width and height of the image. And I don't think that'll be an issue..